# Creating a video using frames in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

```
def make_vid(file_path, frames, fps):
  w,h ,l = frames[0].shape
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
  writer = cv2.VideoWriter(file_path,fourcc, fps, (w, h))

  for frame in frames:
      writer.write(frame)

  writer.release()
```

This is my function of creating videos using frames.
I input a video and use cv.read to read the frames. I then store it in frames[] and then call this function but the video it makes, its always corrupted. Not sure where I am wrong.

EDIT:

```
ret, frame = capture.read()
while ret:
        frames.append(frame)
        ret, frame = capture.read()
```

this is how I read

Comment: You surely don't load all the frames for an entire video into memory then pass them to this function??? How much RAM do you have? How long are your videos?

Comment: show us information on the resulting file. -- **before** you write the frames, check and make sure they're all the same size.

Comment: I do delete some frames but how does that matter ?

Comment: If your video is 1080p at 30fps it will take 1920x1080x3x30 or 180MB of RAM for each second of video. That's why I asked you how long your video is and how much RAM you have.

Comment: I have 16 gb of ram and video is 1 minute long at 30 fps

Answer (score -1):

What kind of corruption you see? Have you checked the frames you are reading. Do they have any sort of corruption? If you can share the code I might be able to help you. It might be an issue of reading the frames. Here's a code for reading video frames.

```
frames=[]
cap=cv2.VideoCapture('vid.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,img=cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frames.append(img)
    else: 
        break

cap.release()
```

Comment: that is **bad code**. error-check the opening and reading of that VideoCapture

Comment: Please see the edit now

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Sorry I've gotten a bit rusty. I've made some change.

Comment: @HarshitGupta Could be a problem with reading. Try with `if ret:` instead of `while ret:` and use  `while(capture.isOpened()):` outside the video reading code you've posted above